# How to edit a file in Jenkins before building the app?

Tags: jenkins

Currently in my Jenkins pipeline script, I have this:

```
stage ('get_repo'){

checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
          branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
          extensions: [], 
          submoduleCfg: [], 
          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'git', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/myrepo.git']]])

}
stage ('build'){
    bat "npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular"
    bat 'C:\\Users\\user1\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng.cmd build --aot'
}
stage ('create artifact'){
 archiveArtifacts 'dist//**'
 }}}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

1. The repository has a file called env.ts but it has some static ip address. The static ip address is only applicable to one of our branches. I want to be able to edit that env.ts file to contain the correct ip address for that build before running the next stage which is the build stage. I am running this on a windows jenkins node. The file content is like this:

export const environment = {
  apiServer: 'http://1.1.1.1:80',
  production: true,
  paginationLimit: 10,
};

I want to change the value of apiServer from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2

2. Once the file contents has been changed, i want the file renamed to environment.ts

How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are making use of Jenkins and it is on a windows machine. You can make use of PowerShell to change the file content and rename it

Here in this example,

```
(Get-Content C:\proj\Jenkins\workspace\QA\env.ts).replace('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2') | Set-Content C:\proj\Jenkins\workspace\QA\env.ts
Rename-Item -Path "C:\proj\Jenkins\workspace\QA\env.ts" -NewName "environment.ts"
```

Thanks,
[xyzcoder.github.io](https://xzcoder.github.io)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve what you want. I see you are using Windows, so I would go for Powershell which makes such operations easy. You can setup regex or simply replace 1.1.1.1 with 2.2.2.2. Renaming file is also really easy (Rename-Item cmdlet). Powershell is also supported in jenkins pipeline.

Example powershell script:

```
$path = "C:\env.ts"
$content = Get-Content -Path $path
$content -replace [regex]::escape("1.1.1.1"),"2.2.2.2" | Out-File $path
Rename-Item -Path $path -NewName "environment.ts"
```

[Here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/) you have examples showing how to invoke powershell code from Jenkins pipeline.